# How to change a key to act like another one in C++

Tags: winapi

I want to see how can I change a key on keyboard to act like another key.
for example by clicking Alt I want the system think it is Ctrl using c++, is it possible?

Comment: (assuming you are on Windows, C++ alone will not let you do that. you need to add a Windows hook. have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419562

Comment: On what OS? Admin allowed or not?

Comment: It is on windows and yes the admin is allowed I am the admin

Comment: @Max - using the Windows Hook API calls can be done with only C++.

Comment: This is not really a C++ question, C++ as a language does not even have the concepts of ctrl and alt keys as far as I know. This is operating system question. Please re-tag and add more details to question text.

Comment: It **is** a C++ question, just not **only** a C++ question. (I've edited his tags.)

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants to write a program that'd allow him to arbitrarily remap keys AND wants to write as much as possible of it in C++?

Comment: @Chiffa Yes completly correct, I want to make a key works exactly as Ctrl does and I want to do it with c++ because I know it the best

Comment: All right, now your intent is clear for all. But, as stated, you can't do it in C++ only.

Comment: This isn't even a programming question. It's a system configuration question. You can create a custom keyboard layout or swap the keys at the driver level. Many options given [here](http://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key).

Answer (score 2):

If you are on windows then you may interested to know [LowLevelKeyboardProc callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [HOOKS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> **HOOKS**
>
> A hook is a point in the system message-handling mechanism where an
> application can install a subroutine to monitor the message traffic in
> the system and process certain types of messages before they reach the
> target window procedure.
>
> **LowLevelKeyboardProc callback function**
>
> An application-defined or library-defined callback function used with
> the SetWindowsHookEx function. The system calls this function every
> time a new keyboard input event is about to be posted into a thread
> input queue. The HOOKPROC type defines a pointer to this callback
> function. LowLevelKeyboardProc is a placeholder for the
> application-defined or library-defined function name.

Also check **[Using Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks for your information, do you have any example of using hooks?

Comment: @amiralishahinpour:- Just added a link from which you may get some help!!! Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not an identical, situation, but [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437158/c-win32-keyboard-events) about C++ Win32 keyboard events may give you the start you need.